# Trigger a User Form and vba macro by scanning a QR code

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

I'm looking for a way to scan a QR code that will open my excel document, display a user form to input the status and display data for a piece of equipment, then save that data on a new row in excel. I have a macro that can take a user form and save the inputs as needed, but I'm wondering if there is a way to open to the user form and prefill some of the fields based on the QR code that is scanned. I have implemented web-based QR code scanners before that parsed and used a provided string to fill out a form but have never used it to trigger a vba macro.

I've tried pasting the file share link in the url for a generated qr code but none of the generated codes would accept the share link as the url. My initial train of thought was to follow the share url with parameters and somehow parse the parameters into the user form. I might be tackling this from too much of a "web app" mentality but I'm not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

QR codes do support URI schemes: that means you can either use an URN to open your local excel file or one from a distant server using both syntax:

`ms-excel:ofv|u|<https://example.com/yourfile.xlsx>`

`ms-excel:ofv|u|</local/path/yourfile.xlsx>`

Or directly using HTTP to download, then open a distant document with the prefered editor:

`https://example.com/yourfile.xlsx`

You may need to generate the QR code programatically instead of online editors, because not all of them do support a non HTTP URI scheme.

However, I have not found a way yet to pass argument in the URI scheme and make excel retrieve it.